# Confused about USB3.2 specifications and capabilites. Why does my USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20Gbit/s) throttle but USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 (10Gbit/s) does not?

Tags: usb, usb-3

I want to connect 4 Basler industry cameras to my laptop. I therefore bought a USB3.2 Hub, which I connected to my fastest Port USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20Gbit/s). Laptop: ThinkPad P15 Gen 2i (11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz )

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Release: 22.04 Codename: jammy

The Hub used: https://amzn.eu/d/2ClrEKN

```
lsusb shows the following: 
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 20000M/x2
   |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
       |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
       |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
       |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
       |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
       |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
```

If I open and run pylonviewer (https://www.baslerweb.com/de-de/software/pylon/pylon-viewer/) and start filming with all 4 cameras it starts to throttle.

However if I use my second fastest USB Port on my Laptop USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 (10Gbit/s) lsusb shows the following and it runs flawlessly

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
   |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
       |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
           |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
               |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
   |__ Port 2: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
       |__ Port 3: Dev 14, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
       |__ Port 3: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
       |__ Port 4: Dev 47, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
       |__ Port 4: Dev 47, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
       |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 52, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 52, If 2, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 52, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 51, If 2, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 51, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 51, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
```

In order for the USB Hub to connect I used and USB-A to UBS-c adapter. See the summary in this image as well:
[image]

My question:

Why is it like that? I would expect the faster port to run flawlessly. I am asking as I want to design a custom PC that fits the specification to run 4 cameras simultaneously and I would normally go for the faster port. But which parameters should I actually check in order to make sure it will work with other boards / manufacturers?

### Update:

(readded lost picture due to migration)
As suggested I will try with a industry level hub: https://www.2direct.de/computer/hubs-switches/usb-3.1/3579/usb-c-3.2-gen-2-7-port-combo-hub-industrieausfuehrung
Unfortunately we are bound to a hub in our environment.
If problem persists with this hub, I will update my post again.

Comment: The Amazon page for that hub is vague and contradictory about what it actually supports. If you instead check with the manufacturer you may get a better idea. Regardless, if using Type-A, then both of those ports are running in (at most) 10Gbit x1 mode since a Type A cable cannot do do the 20gbit x2 mode.

Comment: What do you expect from a hub that is sold on Amazon and based on the fact that it requires Type-A to Type-A cable to connect to a PC it cannot be USB compliant, especially if the cable allows powering the hub too, such a cable is specifically not allowed to exist as per USB specs.

Comment: I bought an industry level hub (see description). Nothing changed. It does behave exactly as the cheap Amazon one. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Justme points out the bizarre, non-compliant USB connector on that hub.  Combined with the vague and contradictory specs, and the fact that using 4x 5gbit cameras with a single 10gbit link is not ideal, I would probably just trash it.

I have previously speced out a machine for parallel imaging from a number of USB cameras where bandwidth and reliability (no dropped frames while imaging at high speed) were critical. I found two options that worked well, neither of which involved hubs.

**1. Use the system USB ports**

Modern PC chipsets provide 5-10 USB first-party 10gbit ports which are built into the chipset and thus connected directly to the CPU with a high bandwidth PCIe link:

[image]

See:  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/chipsets/desktop-chipsets/z790-chipset-brief.html

These tend to be highly performant and widely compatible.  They are also free and usually my first choice.  If you're picking out a new system, get one with a motherboard that gives you 6+ 10g ports and you are good to go.

**2. Buy a PCIe card with 4 individual USB 10g controllers**

These are more pricey (> $100), but you can buy PCIe cards that connect 4 PCIe lanes to 4 individual USB 10gbit controllers.  This will give you the maximum bandwidth, and in my experience these also tend to be fairly reliable without too much compatibility weirdness.  You can find much cheaper cards, but these will typically share bandwidth and so may have the same issues as your hub.  Given the cost of your cameras, probably not worth finding out to save $150.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford Basler cameras, you can afford a proper industrial USB hub, with support from the manufacturer and/or distributor, etc. For production use, don't buy anything electronic on Amazon - it's all around a bad idea, as you have no recourse other than a return. Suppose that hub you got has a fake CE marking and will cause EMI problems when you'll be testing your product. That alone will cost you so much money, that the price of an industrial hub made by a company you can easily contact will be negligible in comparison.

For all we know, the hub you bought has some board, firmware or silicon bugs that make it misbehave. It looks super sketchy to me anyways. You'd need a proper USB analyzer to figure all of it out anyway, so I'd highly suggest renting one for a bit, but only if a proper HUB doesn't fix your problem. What is cheaper: renting an analyzer for a week, and days of your time, or buying a proper hub from DigiKey, Allied Electronics, industrial supply houses, etc.?

You should also be buying the USB cables from a catalog distributor like DigiKey. If you bought them on Amazon, AliExpress, etc., they are OK for hobby use only, not for product development as - again - your time wasted on troubleshooting will delete any savings, and will make the project more expensive.

If this is for a hobby project then of course this is all moot, and you can do whatever you want, just accepting "well, it doesn't work on that port, weird but OK". That's fine for a hobby project. Such workarounds are fairly typical when getting cheap system components working together for a hobby project.

Comment: I bought an industry level hub (see description). Nothing changed. It does behave exactly as the cheap Amazon one. Any thoughts?